# NSTimeInterval to HH:mm:ss?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, cocoa-touch

If I have an NSTimeInterval that is set to say 200.0, is there a way to convert that into 00:03:20, I was thinking I could initialise an NSDate with it and then use NSDateFormatter using HH:mm:ss. My question is, is there a quick way to do this or do I have to break up the number myself and use `[NSString stringWithFormat: %02d:%02d:%02d, myHour, myMin, mySec]`?

Answer (score 201, accepted):

No need to use `NSDateFormatter` or anything else than division and modulo. `NSTimeInterval` is just a double containing seconds.

**Swift**

```
func stringFromTimeInterval(interval: NSTimeInterval) -> String {
    let interval = Int(interval)
    let seconds = interval % 60
    let minutes = (interval / 60) % 60
    let hours = (interval / 3600)
    return String(format: "%02d:%02d:%02d", hours, minutes, seconds)
}
```

**Objective-C**

```
- (NSString *)stringFromTimeInterval:(NSTimeInterval)interval {
    NSInteger ti = (NSInteger)interval;
    NSInteger seconds = ti % 60;
    NSInteger minutes = (ti / 60) % 60;
    NSInteger hours = (ti / 3600);
    return [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%02ld:%02ld:%02ld", (long)hours, (long)minutes, (long)seconds];
}
```

Comment: Much appreciated, thats what I was thinking but I just wanted to check that I was not missing something already included as part of the iOS SDK.

Comment: I want to point out that ":" works as a delimiter only in English and some other languages. Finnish, for example, uses "." - like this "15.02.59"

Comment: @sgosha, exactly, normally Apple tends to provide formatters for these.  Should I instead use a localized string for formatting?

Comment: @Gerry Apple does not have a formatter class for that, so in our app we use localized versions of "%@:%@" and "%@:%@:%@". please note that hours and minutes should also be localized - use NSNumberFormatter for that.

Comment: this is the wrong answer since it doesn't localize the delimiter (as other comments mention). using NSDateCompomentsFormatter you can correctly format your time interval in a single line, e.g. `NSDateComponentsFormatter().stringFromTimeInterval(NSTimeInterval(duration))` in swift

Comment: For localization and future proofing, the correct solution is to use NSDateComponentsFormatter as described by @jrc

Comment: If you want to have just hour and day use this
+ (NSString *)stringFromTimeInterval:(NSTimeInterval)interval {
    NSInteger ti = (NSInteger)interval;
NSString *string =EMPTY_STRING;
    
    NSInteger hours = (ti / 3600);
    NSInteger days = (hours / 24);
    
    if (days!=0) string = [string stringByAppendingString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%01ldd", (long)days]];
    if (hours!=0) string = [string stringByAppendingString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@%01ldhr", days==0?@"":@" ",(long)hours]];
    return string;// (long)minutes, (long)seconds
}

Comment: If we want to do this backwards, do we need a formatter?

Comment: Actually, the comments recommending use of `NSDateComponentsFormatter.stringFromTimeInterval` are incorrect. There is no apparently no way to set the reference date of `NSDateComponentsFormatter` when using this function, and it uses the current date to calculate the time interval. This means your durations come back wrong on DST time changes, leap years, leap seconds etc. There might be a way to frig this by specifying a weird NSCalendar instance

Answer (score 106):

On iOS 8, use [`NSDateComponentsFormatter`](http://nshipster.com/nsformatter/#nsdatecomponentsformatter).

```
NSDateComponentsFormatter *dateComponentsFormatter = [[NSDateComponentsFormatter alloc] init];
NSLog(@"%@", [dateComponentsFormatter stringFromTimeInterval:200.0]);
```

outputs "3:20".

```
NSDateComponentsFormatter *dateComponentsFormatter = [[NSDateComponentsFormatter alloc] init];
dateComponentsFormatter.zeroFormattingBehavior = NSDateComponentsFormatterZeroFormattingBehaviorPad;
dateComponentsFormatter.allowedUnits = (NSCalendarUnitHour | NSCalendarUnitMinute | NSCalendarUnitSecond);
NSLog(@"%@", [dateComponentsFormatter stringFromTimeInterval:200.0]);
```

outputs "0:03:20".

Comment: Nice update. But if it's really just such a simple calculation, wouldn't be using these object a huge overhead (as long as there is no dynamic format involved)?

Comment: you need the formatting to ensure the string appears correctly for different locales etc.

Comment: Really tiny comment, but it is weird to give an example of C function for ObjectiveC question. Probably worth changing it into ObjectiveC format?

Comment: Saved me a ton of code! [This is how I used it for OrangeIRC](https://github.com/ahyattdev/OrangeIRC/blob/11ce8079453b9b5ee9bc814f8ffeac2183654545/OrangeIRC%20iOS/UserInfoTableViewController.swift#L102-L117).

Answer (score 18):

**Swift 3** version of **onmyway133**'s answer:

```
import Foundation

func format(_ duration: TimeInterval) -> String {
    let formatter = DateComponentsFormatter()
    formatter.zeroFormattingBehavior = .pad
    formatter.allowedUnits = [.minute, .second]

    if duration >= 3600 {
        formatter.allowedUnits.insert(.hour)
    }

    return formatter.string(from: duration)!
}


print(format(12)) // 0:12
print(format(65)) // 1:05
print(format(1750)) // 29:10
print(format(3890)) // 1:04:50
print(format(45720)) // 12:42:00
```

Comment: Is creating a DateComponentsFormatter expensive performancewise, like a DateFormatter or NumberFormatter?

Comment: Instead of checking if there's an hour value, setting `zeroFormattingBehavior` to be `[.dropLeading, .pad]` might be a better (less code) option.

Comment: The comments appear to be incorrect. This code results in: 
00:12,
01:05,
29:10,
01:04:50,
12:42:00

Answer (score 10):

Some extra lines of code, but I feel using NSDateComponents will give a more precise value.

```
- (NSString *)getTimeRepresentationFromDate:(NSDate *)iDate withTimeInterval:(NSTimeInterval)iTimeInterval {
    NSString *aReturnValue = nil;
    NSDate *aNewDate = [iDate dateByAddingTimeInterval:iTimeInterval]; 

    unsigned int theUnits = NSHourCalendarUnit | NSMinuteCalendarUnit | NSSecondCalendarUnit;
    NSCalendar *aCalender = [NSCalendar currentCalendar];
    NSDateComponents *aDateComponents = [aCalender components:theUnits fromDate:iDate toDate:aNewDate options:0];

    aReturnValue = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d:%d:%d", [aDateComponents hour], [aDateComponents minute], [aDateComponents second]];

    return aReturnValue;
}
```

Comment: The above method uses the 2 dates using which the TimeInterval is created. You can also pass [NSDate date] to iDate parameter as a default value.

Comment: In what way is this "more precise" than the method used by @matthias-bauch?

Comment: with this method u get time interval in seconds, hours , min i.e. in terms of 60 while @matthias-bauch's answer gives you in decimal terms for example if you wait for sufficient time you will see 1 min 79 sec instead of 2 min 19 sec

Comment: This is a much better solution than the accepted solution. The use of ":" is still a problem for internationalization, but at least this is robust across leap days and daylight savings boundaries.

Comment: @AshishPisey The modulo operator prevents anything bigger than 59.

Answer (score 8):

In **Swift 2**, **iOS 8+**. This makes sure we only show hour when necessary

```
func format(duration: NSTimeInterval) -> String {
  let formatter = NSDateComponentsFormatter()
  formatter.zeroFormattingBehavior = .Pad

  if duration >= 3600 {
    formatter.allowedUnits = [.Hour, .Minute, .Second]
  } else {
    formatter.allowedUnits = [.Minute, .Second]
  }

  return formatter.stringFromTimeInterval(duration) ?? ""
}
```

So you have

```
print(format(12)) // 0:12
print(format(65)) // 1:05
print(format(1750)) // 29:10
print(format(3890)) // 1:04:50
print(format(45720)) // 12:42:00
```

Answer (score 5):

## Swift 4

```
DateComponentsFormatter().string(from: <# TimeInterval #>)
```

ex:

```
DateComponentsFormatter().string(from: 59.0)
```

Answer (score 4):

```
NSTimeInterval ti = 3667;
double hours = floor(ti / 60 / 60);
double minutes = floor((ti - (hours * 60 * 60)) / 60);
double seconds = floor(ti - (hours * 60 * 60) - (minutes * 60));
```

Answer (score 3):

To "extend" Matthias Bauch's suggestion, in Swift I would make this a computed property of NSTimeInterval:

```
extension NSTimeInterval {
  var stringValue: String {
    let interval = Int(self)
    let seconds = interval % 60
    let minutes = (interval / 60) % 60
    let hours = (interval / 3600)
    return String(format: "%02d:%02d:%02d", hours, minutes, seconds)
  }
}
```

The advantage of this is it's attached to the `NSTimeInterval` type, not your view controller or wherever else you put that function. To use you'd go something like:

```
let timeInterval = NSDate().timeIntervalSinceDate(start)        
self.elapsedTimeLabel.text = timeInterval.stringValue
```

Comment: Thanks, Kenny! In my case I needed them separately, so I added additional variables to your extension: "var seconds: Int { let interval = Int(self); let seconds = interval % 60; return seconds }" and so on for minutes and hours. So that usage will be: print("minutes spent: \(timeInterval.minutes)")

Answer (score 2):

Based on answer by @onmyway133 here is the Swift 4 version:

```
func format(duration: TimeInterval) -> String {
    let formatter = DateComponentsFormatter()
    formatter.zeroFormattingBehavior = .pad

    if duration >= 3600 {
        formatter.allowedUnits = [.hour, .minute, .second];
    } else {
        formatter.allowedUnits = [.minute, .second];
    }

    return formatter.string(from: duration) ?? "";
}
```

Answer (score 0):

straight from apple docs:
in h file:

```
 @property(strong,nonatomic)NSDateComponentsFormatter *timerFormatter;
```

in m file

```
@synthesize timerFormatter;

- (void)viewDidLoad {
[super viewDidLoad];
NSDateComponentsFormatter *timerFormatter = [[NSDateComponentsFormatter alloc] init];
timerFormatter.unitsStyle = NSDateComponentsFormatterUnitsStylePositional; 
//10:59 Positional THIS ONE DOES NOT SEEM TO WORK iOS<9 WHEN <1Minute JUST SHOWS 01, 10m 59s Abbreviated, 10min 59sec Short, 10minutes 59seconds Full ...
timerFormatter.allowedUnits = NSCalendarUnitHour|NSCalendarUnitMinute|NSCalendarUnitSecond;
}
```

whereever you need to convert your NSTimeInterval timeInterval to hh:mm:ss string, do this:

```
NSString *txt=[timerFormatter stringFromTimeInterval:timeInterval];
```

Answer (score 0):

I guess, the timer fraction should be ceiled out. 
As Matthias' code was creating that issue in seconds, I use the following slightly modified from that of Matthias

```
    - (NSString *)stringFromTimeInterval:(NSTimeInterval)interval {
        int ti = (int) ceil(interval);
        int seconds = ti % 60;
        int minutes = (ti / 60) % 60;
        int hours = (ti / 3600);
        return [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%02d:%02d:%02d",hours, minutes, seconds];
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

**Objective C** version of **onmyway133's** answer

```
- (NSString*) formatTimeInterval:(NSTimeInterval) timeInterval {

    NSDateComponentsFormatter *formatter = [[NSDateComponentsFormatter alloc] init];

    formatter.zeroFormattingBehavior = NSDateComponentsFormatterZeroFormattingBehaviorPad;

    if (timeInterval > 3600) {
        formatter.allowedUnits = NSCalendarUnitHour | NSCalendarUnitMinute | NSCalendarUnitSecond;
    } else {
        formatter.allowedUnits = NSCalendarUnitMinute | NSCalendarUnitSecond;
    }

    return [formatter stringFromTimeInterval:timeInterval];
}
```