# NSDate Formatter in an NSTimer

Tags: ios

So I have an NSTimer and im using a date formatter to pause and play the timer but when i start the timer it starts at 07:00:00 when i want it to start at 00:00:00.

My timer code is

```
-(void) updateTimer {

    NSDate *currentDate = [NSDate date];

    NSTimeInterval timeInterval = [currentDate timeIntervalSinceDate:startDate];
    NSDate *timerDate = [NSDate dateWithTimeIntervalSince1970:timeInterval];

    NSDateFormatter *dateFormatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
    dateFormatter.dateFormat = @"hh:mm:ss";
    //[dateFormatter setTimeZone:[NSTimeZone timeZoneForSecondsFromGMT:0.0]];

    NSString *timeString = [dateFormatter stringFromDate:timerDate];
    hhmmssLabel .text = timeString;
    pauseTimeInterval = timeInterval;

}

-(void)pauseTimer {

    [tickerTimer invalidate];
    tickerTimer = nil;
    [self updateTimer];
}

-(void) unPauseTimer {

    startDate = [NSDate date] ;
    startDate = [startDate dateByAddingTimeInterval:((-1)*(pauseTimeInterval))];
    tickerTimer = [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:1.0/1.0 target:self selector:@selector(updateTimer) userInfo:nil repeats:YES];
}
```

Im assuming it has to do with the time zone so i commented it out which didnt help. I can't get it to start at 00:00:00

Comment: Yes, it almost certainly has to do with timezone.

Comment: Do you want the timer to start at midnight local time?

Comment: @BlackFrog I want it to start when the unPauseTimer function is called

Comment: I am now reading your question. To convert NSTimeInterval to HH:mm:ss just [follow this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4933075/nstimeinterval-to-hhmmss).  I would not keep track of pause time in the update timer.  I will write a more detail answer below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you can simplify you code a litte.  Your requirements are not too complicated (you are just dealing with intervals not absolute dates), so it would be ok to use something [like this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8128243/296446):

```
NSDate * currentDate = [NSDate date];
NSTimeInterval timeInterval = [currentDate timeIntervalSinceDate:startDate];

// NSTimeInterval is in measured in Seconds
NSInteger hours = ( (NSInteger) timeInterval / 3600.0 );
NSInteger mins  = ( (NSInteger) (timeInterval / 60) % 60 );
NSInteger secs  = ( (NSInteger) timeInterval % 60.0 );

NSString * timeString = [NSString stringWithFormat:%02u:%02u:%02u, hours, mins, secs];
```

Otherwise try to look at [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8128197/296446).  Perhapse you need `@"HH:mm:ss"` (for 24 hour time) or `[NSTimeZone timeZoneWithName:@"UTC"]];`

Comment: Well this works fine for 1 second then crashes, any ideas why?

Comment: I Used a mix of your answer and that link you gave me and it all works flawlessly thanks for the help