# Xcode Swift Stopwatch App

Tags: ios, xcode, swift, timer

I have a stopwatch app I'm making that currently shows the minutes, seconds and milliseconds on a UILabel.  It has a 'Start' button and a 'Stop' button.  The code is below.  How do I add hours to it? Also how do I make it continue where it was, when I stopped it?  Currently if I press start again, it resets and starts over.  I'll add a reset button later.

```
//Variables
var startTime = NSTimeInterval()

//Start Button
@IBAction func start(sender: AnyObject) {
   let aSelector : Selector = “updateTime”
   timer = NSTimer.scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval(0.01, target: self, selector: aSelector, userInfo: nil, repeats: true)
   startTime = NSDate.timeIntervalSinceReferenceDate()
}

//Stop Button
@IBAction func stop(sender: AnyObject) {
   timer.invalidate()
}

//Update Time Function
func updateTime() {

   var currentTime = NSDate.timeIntervalSinceReferenceDate()

   //Find the difference between current time and start time.

   var elapsedTime: NSTimeInterval = currentTime - startTime

   //calculate the minutes in elapsed time.

   let minutes = UInt8(elapsedTime / 60.0)

   elapsedTime -= (NSTimeInterval(minutes) * 60)

   //calculate the seconds in elapsed time.

   let seconds = UInt8(elapsedTime)

   elapsedTime -= NSTimeInterval(seconds)

   //find out the fraction of milliseconds to be displayed.

   let fraction = UInt8(elapsedTime * 100)

   //add the leading zero for minutes, seconds and millseconds and store them as string constants

   let strMinutes = String(format: "%02d", minutes)
   let strSeconds = String(format: "%02d", seconds)
   let strFraction = String(format: "%02d", fraction)

   //concatenate minuets, seconds and milliseconds as assign it to the UILabel

   displayTimeLabel.text = “\(strMinutes):\(strSeconds):\(strFraction)”

}
```

Comment: Please, use [code blocks](http://stackoverflow.com/editing-help#code) for describing your question instead of include screenshots of your code. This make copy & paste possible, among other things.You can also configure the [highlighting of your code](http://stackoverflow.com/editing-help#syntax-highlighting).

Comment: Ok, sorry and thank you!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can calculate hours so

```
elapsedtime / 3600
```

Read there more [NSTimeInterval to HH:mm:ss?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4933075/nstimeinterval-to-hhmmss)

Comment: Great thank you.  Do you know how to make it so it continues to count on the stopwatch and not reset when I click start again?

Comment: @ChallengerGuy please write me to email

Comment: How do I do that?  I"m new to this whole stack overflow thing.

Answer (score 0):

To make continues to count on the stopwatch:

Create `var stopTime : NSTimeInterval = 0`

When stop() function is called, insert this code:

```
 stopTime = elapsedTime
```

In start() function, replace to:

```
elapsedTime = (currentTime - startTime) + stopTime
```

Or You can use NSDate(), NSDateFormatter() to solve this problem.
Reference here [enter link description here](https://github.com/Phamngocquynh/StopWatch/blob/master/ViewController.swift)