# how to seperate '72250' in 72 hr and 250 min in objective c?

Tags: ios

Actually I got time interval as 750, so I want split-up in hours and minutes. I was trying but still unable to get. I did following code.

```
NSTimeInterval interval = 750;
 NSDateComponentsFormatter *componentFormatter = [[NSDateComponentsFormatter alloc] init];

componentFormatter.unitsStyle = NSDateComponentsFormatterUnitsStylePositional;
componentFormatter.zeroFormattingBehavior = NSDateComponentsFormatterZeroFormattingBehaviorDropAll;

NSString *formattedString = [componentFormatter stringFromTimeInterval:interval];
NSLog(@"%@",formattedString);
```

Comment: from where you get this time?? from API?

Comment: Maybe this helps you http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4933075/nstimeinterval-to-hhmmss

Comment: FYI, a `NSTimeInterval` of 750 does not represent 7 hours and 50 minutes. It represents seconds, so 750 seconds are 12.5 minutes (12 min 30 secondes).

Comment: Thank you so much ,but i'm looking for different one .

Answer (score 0):

I think this will help you

```
- (NSString *)timeInteralToString:(NSTimeInterval)interval {
    NSInteger ti = (NSInteger)interval;
    NSInteger seconds = ti % 60;
    NSInteger minutes = (ti / 60) % 60;
    NSInteger hours = (ti / 3600);
    return [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%02ld:%02ld", (long)hours, (long)minutes];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This Works Correctly:

```
NSString *value1 = @"7570";      //This is Value
NSNumberFormatter *numberFormatter = [[NSNumberFormatter alloc] init];
numberFormatter.usesGroupingSeparator = YES;
[numberFormatter setLocale:[NSLocale localeWithLocaleIdentifier:@" "]];
NSString *formatted = [NSString stringWithFormat: @"%@", [value1 substringWithRange:NSMakeRange(0,2)] ];
NSString *str=[formatted stringByAppendingString:@"hr"];
NSString *formatted2 = [NSString stringWithFormat: @"%@", [value1 substringWithRange:NSMakeRange(2,2)]];
NSString *str2=[formatted2  stringByAppendingString:@"mm"];
NSLog(@"%@",[str stringByAppendingString:str2]);
```

Comment: above code output is:2016-03-22 15:52:35.532 timeDemo[778:23132] 75hr70mm